# Share methods of a service but keep data separated for every controller in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Which is the best way to share the functionality of a service between controllers but serve different data to each controller?

I've found that keeping data persistence in a service is a great solution to release the controllers from potentially duplicated logic. But if I need another controller to use the service then data will be shared between controllers.

What is the best way to serve different data to different controllers from the same service? I've thought of something similar to the Observer pattern. The service would keep a collection of the controllers and create an instance of the data for each.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure the functionality that you share does not depend on shared data

e.g.

```
 app.service("abc" , function(){

   var sharedWork = function(x) {
  /// some logic here
  }

return {
 sharedWork : sharedWork
}
```

});

I know above code is very simple, but wanted to show you that... sharedWork's output just depends on its input hence can be re-used across controllers...

Comment: Most of the time I'm using my services to keep the data coming from a REST endpoint and expose it to the controllers. But I like the idea of not returning the entire service. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Define four different services that share the same implementation.

```
function SomeSrvc(foo, bar) {
}

myApp.service('srvc1', ['foo', 'bar', SomeSrvc]);
myApp.service('srvc2', ['foo', 'bar', SomeSrvc]);
myApp.service('srvc3', ['foo', 'bar', SomeSrvc]);
myApp.service('srvc4', ['foo', 'bar', SomeSrvc]);
```

Comment: What if we have n controllers?

Comment: Then think up a convention (`SomeController` -> `SomeService`) and write some JavaScript that calls `myApp.service(serviceName, dependencies)` with the right parameters. Or obviously rethink your whole application because something might be terribly wrong.